# LinkedList based tree in java

Tags: java, tree, linked-list

I'm trying to generate a tree using linkedlist in Java but im struggling, 
i want the tree to be like this; if the root is ("1", "2", "3")
child1 will be ("2", "3"), child2 will be ("1", "3") child3 ("1", "2")
the second level child nodes will be for child1; child11 ("2")  and child12 ("3")
and so on, i wrote this code using linkedlist

```
public class BBTree<T> {

T NodeMembers;
BBTree<T> Parent;
List<BBTree<T>> Children;

public BBTree() {

}
public BBTree(T Nodes){
    this.NodeMembers = Nodes;
    this.Parent = null;
    this.Children = new LinkedList<BBTree<T>>();
}
public BBTree<T> addChild (T Nodes){
    BBTree<T> child = new BBTree<T>();
    child.Parent = this;
    child.NodeMembers = Nodes;
    this.Children.add(child);
    return child;
}
public void ChildrenMembers(){
    List<String> parentMembers = (List<String>) this.NodeMembers;
    Iterator<String> i = parentMembers.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()){
        String LeftValue = i.next();
        List<String> copy = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (String ChildMember : parentMembers ){
            if (!LeftValue.equals(ChildMember))
                copy.add(ChildMember);
        }
        T copy2 = (T)copy;
        this.addChild(copy2);
    }
}
```

to it works for adding the child nodes level by level 
this is how i did a first test

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    BBTree<List<String>> tree = new BBTree<List<String>>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"));
    tree.ChildrenMembers();
    System.out.println("the root is "+ tree.NodeMembers);
    Iterator<BBTree<List<String>>> i = tree.Children.iterator();


    while (i.hasNext()){
        BBTree<List<String>> node = i.next();
        System.out.println("the child is "+ node.NodeMembers);
    }

}
```

i can't figure out how to generate the tree automatically for if i have a list with 70 strings at the root for example
any help is really appreciated

Comment: You can't keep a tree with 70 strings at the root in memory. Since the root node would have 70 children, `70 * 69` grandchildren, ... So the number of leafs in your tree would be `70!` (approx. `10^100`). You can't expect to keep that in memory!

Comment: it will not be necessarily all the child nodes, there will be evaluation of every node if i will generate child nodes or not
so it might stop at the third level, but how do i get it to generate automatically

Comment: Sorry but I really don't get what your problem is. Please edit your question to make that clear. (In your question it seems like you want to generate the whole tree, your comment suggests something else)

Comment: sorry @fabian, I didnt give more details as i thought it will make it more complicated. 
Im trying to use the tree to solve an optimization problem using Branch&Bound algorithm. there's an upper and lower bound for the solution, the root is the optimum solution when starting, then we try to find a subset that can deliver a better solution and still satisfy the bounds, if a child can not satisfy one of the bounds then non of its children can and the branch would be eliminated. otherwise will generate children in the search for the optimum solution. i just cant figure how to generate children